# Error when using file_exist in array php?

Tags: php

I have a sample

```
$image_src = array(
'image1.jpg',  //Yes
'image2.jpg',  //This image is 404
'image3.jpg'   //Yes
);
for($i=0; $i<count($image_src); $i++) {
   if(!file_exists($image_src[$i])) {
      $image_src[$i] = 'image_change.jpg';
   }
}
print_r($image_src);
```

But when run result show all `image_change.jpg`

```
[0] => 'image_change.jpg',
[1] => 'image_change.jpg',
[2] => 'image_change.jpg'
```

Result exactly is:

```
[0] => 'image1.jpg',
[1] => 'image_change.jpg',
[2] => 'image3.jpg'
```

=>How to fix it

Comment: Are the images in the same directory as this php file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file name must be the complete path of the file,  make sure you set the base directory of the files before calling.

```
for($i=0; $i<count($image_src); $i++) {
   if(!file_exists($imageBaseDir . '/'. $image_src[$i])) {
      $image_src[$i] = 'image_change.jpg';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php), not `file_exist()`.

Comment: PHP file would generate an error then or not?

Comment: If error reporting and displaying is turned on then using `file_exist` will indeed generate an error.